# Change the code below from DAX to Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Can someone help me to transfer this code to Power Query. I found this one in dax, but I would prefer to have it done already in the data transformation.

Avg Activation Time =
var Oppy_id = 'Calculation'[Reference number]

Return
AVERAGEX(
FILTER(ALL('Calculation'), 'Calculation'[Reference number] = Oppy_id),
'Calculation'[Activation (wd)])

---

Comment: sure. what does it do

Comment: It calculates the avarage days (Activation days) for the same ID (Reference number)
Example: An ID can have multiple rows with different sub IDs and different Activation days

Comment: Please **Edit your question** to show an example of sample data, **as text which can be copy/pasted**, along with a screen shot of your desired results from that data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without examples of your data and desired output, it is not possible to be more specific, but this should get you started.

In PQ to average values that are linked to a particular group (ID), you would `GroupBy` the ID, and select `Average` for the aggregation (with Activation Days for the Value column.

In M, it would look generally like:

```
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Previous Step", {"ID"}, {
        {"Average Activation Days", each List.Average([Activation Days]), type nullable number}
        }),
```

In your code, the step would have different references for the previous step, and possibly for the column.